# SoapHandler not called after WS operation is executed

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, soaphandler

I have a servlet that also consumes SOAP WS (in doGet). I want to see SOAP envelope (or anything else in soap message). I adddd this code to my servlet class:

```
class ClientHandlerResolver implements HandlerResolver {
    public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo port_info) {
        List<Handler> hchain = new ArrayList<Handler>();
        hchain.add(new TestHandler()); //  soap handler defined in TestHandler.java dumps messages to stdout
        return hchain;
    }
}
```

I a separate class, i have my TestHandler:

```
public class TestHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
private static final String LoggerName = "ClientSideLogger";
private Logger logger;
private final boolean log_p = true; // set to false to turn off 

public TestHandler() { 
logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggerName);
 }

public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext ctx) {
if (log_p) 
    logger.info("Test::handleMessage"); 

// Is this an outbound message, i.e., a request?
Boolean request_p = (Boolean)
      ctx.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

// Manipulate the SOAP only if it's a request
  if (request_p) {
    try {
        SOAPMessage msg = ctx.getMessage(); 
        msg.writeTo(System.out);

    }
    catch(SOAPException e) 
    { System.err.println(e); 
    }
    catch(IOException e) 
    { System.err.println(e); 
    }
}
  return true; // continue down the chain
```

}

```
public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext ctx) {
  return true;
```

}

```
public Set<QName> getHeaders() { 
if (log_p)
    logger.info("getHeaders");
return null;
```

}

```
public void close(MessageContext messageContext) { 
if (log_p)
    logger.info("close");
}
```

}

Nothing is printed out when i make WS request. I don't even know if handler is called.

How to see printouts defined in Handler?

Comment: You haven't shown how you tie your handler resolver into service invocation. Do you use something like `javax.xml.ws.Service.setHandlerResolver`?

Comment: Hm, i don't have anything like that. Where should i put it, as a parameter to my webservice call?

Comment: What does the code look like for invoking the service? Do you use the `Service` class?

Comment: I just create MyService_ServiceLocator and MyService_Port objects and then call my operations on MyService_Port object like p.getApples(); All my code for WS client was generated from WSDL in Eclipse.

Comment: Aha, i found out that i should call setHandlerResolver() on my service object. Problem is there is no such method in my generated Eclipse generated classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what Eclipse is generating for you, but here's one way to do it. Assume `MyService` is the interface generated from the WSDL:

```
URL wsdlURL = new URL("...");
QName serviceName = new QName("...", "...");
Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, serviceName);
HandlerResolver handlerResolver = new ClientHandlerResolver();
service.setHandlerResolver(handlerResolver);
MyService myService = service.getPort(MyService.class);
// invoke methods (operations) on myService
```

Comment: Eclipse generated code for Axis1 didn't allow me to setHandlerResolver. Then i used wsiimport tool from CLI (generates JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6 code) and now i am able to use handlers.